# Does using SealedObjects in Java secure against serialization vunerability?

Tags: java, security, serialization

I understand that Java serialization poses a security risk. Would sealing objects in Java mitigate against this risk? If so, any reason not to use object sealing instead of insecure serialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not on its own. The serialised stream could contain any object, not just `javax.crypto.SealedObject`. You'd still need the new "whitelist" feature.

A much better approach is to secure the entire stream. And then use a different protocol to Java Serialisation without all the magic. Or where possible, just pass a token instead of the data itself.